# Change bibliography numbering style with BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibliographystyle

Is there a way to change the appearance of the reference number using BibLatex with a specific style?

I am using the `phys` style and would like to have the reference numbers appear in square brackets rather than as superscripts. Here is a MWE of what I have at the moment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,linktocpage=true}
\usepackage[giveninits=true,isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,hyperref=true,backend=biber, style=phys]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{PhysRevLett.128.051103}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with `sample.bib` containing

```
@article{PhysRevLett.128.051103,
  title = {Bondi-Metzner-Sachs Group in Five Spacetime Dimensions},
  author = {Fuentealba, Oscar and Henneaux, Marc and Matulich, Javier and Troessaert, C\'edric},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume = {128},
  issue = {5},
  pages = {051103},
  numpages = {5},
  year = {2022},
  month = {Feb},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.128.051103},
  url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.128.051103}
}
```

This produces the output:

[image]

which, apart from the superscript reference number, is the style I wish to achieve including the hyperlink on the journal, issue, pages and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`biblatex-phys`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-phys/biblatex-phys.pdf) has an option called `biblabel` with which you can switch between superscript numbers (the default `biblabel=superscript,`) or bracketed numbers (`biblabel=brackets,`) in the bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=phys,
  giveninits=true,
  isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,
  biblabel=brackets,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bracketed number in the bibliography.]